# How to trace in the console how many intervals are being executed - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a problem trying to know if a setInterval() is taking place or it was killed.
I am creating an interval and saving it into a variable:

```
interval = setInterval('rotate()',3000);
```

Then on click to an element I stop the interval and wait 10 seconds before starting a new one, by the way the variable interval is global:

```
$(elm).click(function(){

  clearInterval(interval);
  position = index;

  $('#banner div').animate({
    'margin-left':position*(-img_width)
  });

  setTimeout('startItnerval()',10000);


});

function startItnerval(){

    interval = setInterval('rotate()',3000);

}
```

It seems to work but eventually I can realize that there are intervals still being in place, everytime I start a new interval it is saved in the interval variable, which is global, so in theory even if I start 100 intervals they are all saved in the same variable replacing the previous interval right? So I should only have one instance of interval; then on  `clearInterval(interval);` it should stop any instance.

After looking at the results, apparently even if it is saved in the same variable, they are all separate instances and need to be killed individually.

How can I trace how many intervals are being executed, and if possible identify them one by one? even if I am able to solve the problem **I really would like to know if there is a way to count or show in the console how many intervals are being executed?**

thanks

Comment: Set your interval like this: `setInterval(rotate, 3000);` - don't pass strings if you can at all help it.

Comment: No, in theory they are **not** all saved in `interval`... if I got you right. You'll need to save every interval ID separately, in an array or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/4xDsF/)***

As pointed out in comments, the id's constantly increase as timers are added to a page. As a result, it may be possible to clear all timers running on a page like this:

```
function clearTimers(){
 var t = window.setTimeout(function(){
  var idMax = t;
  for( var i = 0; i < idMax; i++ ){
   window.clearInterval(i);
   window.clearTimeout(i);
  }
 },4);
}
```

---

The reason that you can only see one interval is because every time you start a new interval, you overwrite the value in `interval`. This causes the previous intervals to be lost but still active.

A suggestion would be to just control access to your variable. Clearly there is an issue where the start function is called too often

```
clearInterval(interval);//when you clear it, null it
interval = null;
```

and then take advantage of that later

```
if( interval != null ){
 interval = setInterval('rotate()',3000);
}
```

Also, as Pointy noted in a comment, using a string to call a function is not best practice. What it basically does is converts it into a `Function` expression which is similar to using `eval`. You should probably either use the function name as a callback

```
setInterval(rotate,3000);
```

or have an anonymous function issue the callback

```
setInterval(function(){ rotate(); },3000);
```

Comment: Ok but is there a way to count or show in the console how many intervals are being executed?

Comment: @EddyXP - Not if you don't keep track of them.

Comment: @EddyXP The `interval` variable will hold the interval id which is a number. The numbers are in sequence. E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/aML83/

Comment: @Bart - Yes. But if you continuously overwrite the id, then there is no way to get it back.

Comment: @TravisJ I was just generating some sequence numbers. That's all

Comment: @Bart - Fair enough. There is definitely a way to track them, but if they are constantly overwritten, then there is no way to know.

Comment: Ok I see, maybe pushing them into an array everytime and get the length of the array? I understand now the issue with overwriting the variable, thanks.

Comment: @Bart - That is a good point about a number sequence, see my edit for an idea about taking advantage of that.

Comment: @EddyXP - Please see edit and fiddle for a possible solution if you do not know the ids but wish to stop them.

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` returns an Id, not the actual object, so no, no interval will be overriden if you repeat the line

```
var xy = setInterval(function() {...}, 1000);
```

If you want to stop the interval you have to clear it:

```
clearInterval(xy);
```

And if your `startInterval` can be called multiple times in a row, but you don't want to create multiple intervals, just clear the inverval before you start a new one:

```
function startInterval(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval('rotate()',3000);
}
```

If you have to create multiple intervals, you could save the ids in an array to keep track of them:

```
var arr = [];

//set the interval
arr.push(setInterval(...));

//get number of currently running intervals
var count = arr.length //gives you the number of currently running intervals

//clear the interval with index i
clearInterval(arr[i]);
arr.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: Yes, on click that is exactly what I do 'clearInterval(interval);' thanks

Comment: the point was that you are not clearing the interval by overwriting the id.